# Proving $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*, 2\sqrt{n+1}-2 \le S_n \le \sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, boundary-value-problem

Suppose the sequence $S_n=\displaystyle \Sigma_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$.

How can I prove that:

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*, 2\sqrt{n+1}-2 \le S_n \le \sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}$$

Answer (score 3):

How? By induction over $n\geqslant1$.

Comment: I think that must be a comment, However I already used induction and tried to prove an inequality using derivative but I failed.

Comment: This is an answer, purposely. Amazing, no? // Which derivative did you use, exactly?

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on Did's answer, which you think is a comment, show that

$$ 2 \sqrt{n+2} - 2 \sqrt{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} } \leq \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n-1}$$

I'd show you one side, say we do the RHS. Multiplying by $\sqrt{n+1}$, it suffices to show that

$$ 1 \leq n+1 - \sqrt{n^2-1},$$

or that

$$\sqrt{n^2-1} \leq n,$$

which is obviously true.

Now you do the LHS.

Comment: Rationalization makes the proof shorter ;)

Comment: @N.S. I was more pissed off that OP didn't think it would work, despite Did's reputation points.

Comment: +1, for the right amount of indications/explicit computations.